# Automated web application testing with Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, web-applications, selenium, automated-tests

I’m trying to use Selenium IDE to automate tests, so that I will not need to redo all the test cases for every update to the website functionality. However, I’m not sure if simple record-replay fashion is able to cope with the tests I need to run. To name a few, these look like (take the logging bit as an example):

- Will a user get e-mail when he/she clicks “I forgot my password”?
- If so, can he/she log in using new details?
- If he/she enters two different passwords, or too short (less than 8
  characters) password, will the system display proper error message?

Tests cover also issues like:
 - “If admin changes rights for a user, will he/she be still able to do
   this or that?”
 or
 - “If a user enters a value into the quantity field, does the system
   check whether it is an integer? If it is, is the total price the
   result of quantity times price minus discount? (remember not every
   product/user is eligible for a discount).”

And so on.
I’ve been looking for some tutorials, but so far I found only explanations on how to install Selenium IDE and do the record-replay. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use record and play for your test development. Your tests will be brittle and you will end up spending time in maintaining those. Write your own code!!

Comment: But what's wrong with using record and play and then exporting the test to Java? I'm more worried about doing complex test cases, not sure if Selenium IDE can handle those.

Comment: IDE is a tool given for people to understand basic stuff. It is not really meant for creating tests at larger scale. IDE does not expose the underlying API that well which you can do yourself. The code readability will go down with ugly Xpaths, You will have to edit your tests more often than not, there will be lots of hard coding, you will also want to make your tests data driven as well..There are  a number of things that go against IDE when you want to develop tests at larger scale..If you want a test or two IDE should be ok or if you are stuck at finding an element or something use IDE

Comment: Ok, what do you suggest then?

Comment: You should use Selenium RC or WebDriver API and write your own tests. I would suggest to use the WebDriver API since it uses the browsers native platform. WebDriver API is part of Selenium 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is more like an action record tool in your case, you still need to use selenium to generate the script/language you like(such as perl, python, java etc.) from the recorded action script, and run it for automated test.

tutorials can be found at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#programming-your-test